# Django RawQuerySet.__repr__ : not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, django, string-formatting, django-queryset

I'm using a `RawQuerySet` in Django, and I need to pass it a few parameters (5).
I'm able to call the constructor using `MyModel.objects.raw(SQL, params)`. The SQL is pretty long and not that relevant, but `params` is `[991L, 991L, 991L, 7L, 3]`.

I do get a `RawQuerySet` in return. Hence, the call is OK.

However, my problem is that when `__repr__` is called (through `print` here), I get a `"Not enough arguments for format string"` error. Now, what I don't get is the following:

1. Why would I not have enough arguments since the call worked?
2. `[m.start() for m in re.finditer('%s', qs.raw_query)]` gives me 5 items and so does `qs.params`.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, but I can't seem to find what.

Comment: how are you calling `__repr__` exactly?

Comment: Using print (When working in the Django shell).

Comment: show us exactly the line that fails. FYI, `print` doesn't call `__repr__`.

Comment: The line that fails is `print qs` - the traceback mentions a call to `__repr__`. I believe that this is because Django's RawQuerySet does not define `__str__`.

Comment: I think you should add more information to your question, like: how are you instancing `qs` (your `RaQuerySet`) or some context around the `print` statement that fails. Without it, it's very difficult for us to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I added some context. The error is however pretty straightforward so I can hardly add more.

Comment: For some reason, you are resisting providing the correct context. *What* is your query? Note that your assumption that "the call worked" just because you get a RawQuerySet back is invalid: querysets are lazy and are not evaluated until iterated (or printed, as in this case).

Comment: Well, I actually iterated over the queryset to check that. The actual reason why I was resisting posting down the SQL was because the request is very long. I could have nevertheless wrote down `params` though - I edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found the explanation. I'm not sure this will be of much help to others, but anyways.

The problem came from the fact that `params` in the call was a `list.` It appears you can use a `list` to instantiate a `RawQuerySet`, but it is not converted into a tuple so you can't use it for string-formatting later on.

Conclusion I'll use `MyModel.objects.raw(SQL, tuple(params))`.

Comment: wow! how did you found that it? This is could be really useful someday to someone else.